# case_when or ifelse with date variables in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to do the following manipulation to my dataset: if date1 > date2 then date1 = date2, else date1.

My current code which is not working:

```
dfnew <- dfold %>% 
  case_when(date1 > date2 ~ date1 == date2)
```

or

```
dfnew <- dfold %>% 
  ifelse(date1 > date2, date1 == date2, date1)
```

For example, if date1 = 2020-06-03 and date2 = 2020-06-01 then date1 = date2.

Neither of these seem to be working for me.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need to see your data and have a better explanation than "not working".  One obvious question is "Are you sure your dates are dates and not characters?".

Comment: there is a syntax error, it should be `case_when(date1 > date2  ~date2, TRUE ~ date1)`

Comment: What do you mean by data1 > data2? Are you comparing the data frame size for example? or the variables' length?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to manipulate a date column inside a data frame (or tibble), you need to wrap your `case_when`/`ifelse` in a `mutate`.  And, as @akrun suggests, correct your syntax error(s).

Comment: Also neither `case_when` nor `ifelse` work on data frames. If `dfold` is a data frame you need to wrap it in `mutate` and define the new column in `mutate`. `dfold %>% mutate(date1 = case_when(date1 > date2  ~date2, TRUE ~ date1))` (or similarly for `ifelse`)

Comment: Though I think this could be simplified as `dfold %>% mutate(date1 = pmin(date1, date2))`.

Comment: Thank you all so much. Didn't know case_when and ifelse did not work on data.frames